# Tabbed documents in Visual Studio - possible to show more detail than the file name?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, namespaces, filenames

I have a solution where I'm repeating various class names within three different projects (a WCF service project, a unit testing project and a BL project). Also partial classes have been used to spread these classes across multiple files.

The net result is that I've got 5 different file names that are repeated across three different projects.

The namespaces of these projects make it clear the purpose of each however Visual studio displays only the filename on each tab when you are in tabbed document mode. This can be a little confusing when switching from file to file.

Is my only option here to rename the file to distinguish between my files or is there a way to persuade VS to show me on each tab which project the file belongs to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no good way to change this behavior other than renaming the files.

You **may** be able to achieve this with a Plugin but it would require a lot of effort and I'm not 100% sure it can be done.

Comment: I have to agree. After posting this (SO is a very good way to force you to think something through completely) I decided that I would add "_Test" after my test project files and "_Service" after the service ones. It's so much easier to work with now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if You switching between open tabs using key stroke CTRL+TAB screen that appear will give you more information

Comment: I just found this recently. Nice feature that is not advertised that well (like many in VS).

Comment: Yes, this is a good point but in a similar vein to my reply to @crizCraig it's still quite slow. User-defined colouring of files in different projects would be a nice touch.

Answer (score 2):

Commercial [Tabs Studio add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com) for Visual Studio allows lots of tab customization. The latest version explicitly demonstrates how to [add project name to tab](http://tabsstudio.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/disambiguator-add-in/) and shows [per-project tab coloring](http://tabsstudio.wordpress.com/2009/09/02/decorator-add-in/).

Answer (score 1):

I can hover over tab names to get a full path of the file. Does this help you?

Comment: This is true and it does help a little but it's still slower than just clicking on the file I want.